# handling models with embedded objects in the payloads with ember data

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to determine how best to define my models. I'm trying to represent an asset. Ex: car, tv, house, etc.

Here's the payload coming from my server:

```
{
    "asset": {
        "id": "1b0b77a2-28d7-488e-9a6f-8a202c297593",
        "created_at": "2015-03-19T09:16:43+0500",
        "updated_at": "2015-03-19T09:16:43+0500",
        "name": "Flat Screen Tv",
        "properties": [
            {
                "name": "brand",
                "value": "Sony",
                "public": false,
                "family": false,
                "friends": false
            },
            {
                "name": "price",
                "value": 1000,
                "public": false,
                "family": false,
                "friends": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It needs to get POSTed back in the same format. How can I define this model with ember data? The properties are hanging me up. I thought I could just define a transformer but then noticed that changing values in the transformed data doesn't update the asset's "dirty" flag. I need that dirty flag to be updated when the properties get changed. Any ideas?

```
// app/transforms/array.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Transform.extend({
  serialize: function(value) {
    return value.toArray();
  },
  deserialize: function(value) {
    return Ember.A(value);
  }
});
```

Here's my asset model definition.

import DS from 'ember-data';

```
// app/models/asset.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('date'),
  properties: DS.attr('array')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties are going to have to be a separate model, and related to your asset models with hasMany. If that doesn't work for you, you might have to rethink how you are storing your properties.

Comment: if i did that, there's still no way of updating the asset's dirty flag if one it's properties changes, right?

Comment: @David Ah. The trick is getting Ember Data to understand that the property whose children you want to embed is part of a relationship so it can sync the store accordingly. To do that you'll want to use [DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html). Note: using this did require me to tweak a custom RESTAdapter I was using, so that may be required in your use case. Let me know if this works for you and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @David Realized I didn't directly answer your question. I think it depends on why you need the asset's dirty flag to be updated. If you change the properties to child models, then you can check whether the asset's properties are dirty, which might work for you instead.

Comment: @moarboilerplace Yeah, that's a very good point. I'll look into that mixin. thanks!

Comment: @David you may run into issues with serializing circular references when trying to return an embedded relationship initially from the server. DS.RESTAdapter also supports sideloaded relationships where you can return the properties beside the asset in the same response instead of embedding them. Details here: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships